# Implementation of Series function

Tags: series-expansion, implementation-details

I'm trying to evaluate the partial derivatives of some function `F[x,y]` at some point, i.e.

```
Limit[Limit[D[F[x,y],{x,m},{y,n}],x->x0],y->y0]
```

However, for higher derivatives I find that it fails to evaluate the limit. On the other hand, if I use the `Series` function

```
Series[F[x,y],{x,x0,m},{y,y0,n}]
```

It produces all the coefficients with no problem. My question is what is the difference between the two methods? what is `Series` assuming that I'm missing when I do it manually with the derivatives?

Comment: What's a good example for `F`?  I see no difference for, say, `Sin[x] Exp[y]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Example `Limit[D[BesselJ[c, x]/x, {x, 3}], x -> 0]` vs `Series[BesselJ[c, x]/x, {x, 0, 3}]` The former times out while the latter gives the right result by looking at the coefficient of `x^3`

Comment: From the result of `Trace`, it seems `Series[BesselJ[c, x]/x, {x, 0, 3}]` is calculated by calculating `Series[1/x, {x, 0, 3}] * Series[BesselJ[c, x], {x, 0, 3}]`.